# Can't Login to Windows 10 -- Sticky Key Issue?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, login, accessibility

Today I tried to login to my desktop happily running Windows 10. I was unable to log in to the computer, because while my mouse worked perfectly, my keyboard wouldn't enter a single key. Instead, I kept hearing a click sound from the speakers every time I pressed a key. I am using a wireless keyboard and mouse from Logitech, and I tried plugging in a wired USB keyboard, to the same effect: only clicks from the keyboard.

Thus, I am unable to enter either my password or PIN code to log into the machine. This is a big problem, because the last time I heard that clicky keyboard sound, it was when I accidently turned on a Windows accessibility feature called Sticky Keys by pressing the shift key too long. That had exactly the same outcome: keyboard wouldn't work, any keypress would result in merely a click sound. I found a workaround -- using my mouse, I opened the control panel, entered Windows accessibility for the keyboard, and turned off sticky keys.

But that was only possibly when I was logged into the machine and it wasn't locked. Now I am locked out and I can't perform this hack.

Any ideas to solve this aggravating catch-22?

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you, as it always seemed to work in Windows 7. With volume turned up as to hear the sound, simple press CTRL and Left Shift at *exactly* the same time.

You should hear a sound that is a lower pitch than the other sounds. It may take a couple try's.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I already did another solution: reboot and use the mouse to do my accessibility hack. This sounds like it could work, too.